# ASP.NET MVC add-migration "project failed to build"

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add a new model and its Data Annotations, when i tried to add the migration using Package Manager Console it show me

> "The project ** project name** failed to build"

This is my model :

````
{
    public class Genre
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}```
````

Comment: And do you see anything in your output, that would give any indication on why it is failing?

Comment: Yes, your project needs to build before you can do a migration. Deal with that first.